# C++ Passing a Pointer to a Pointer to an Object, cannot access members

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

I'm creating a program which creates two objects and passes them down through a large menu with lots of options. The solution I have been using to pass them as arguments has been to create a pointer to a pointer to the objects. However, I am encountering a problem where if I use a pointer to pointer to object as a parameter, I get a compiler error. There is clearly a c++ convention I am not thinking of here.

```
void runMainMenu(Point** ptrPtrPoint)
{
.
.
    *ptrPtrPoint->displayCoord();
.
}
```

As far as I can tell, this operation should be possible, but this is immediately picked up as an error "expression must have pointer-to-class type (which it should when the indirection operator is used with a pointer to a pointer to a class). What is the correct format for passing a pointer to a pointer to an object and accessing the member functions?

Comment: Try using `(*ptrPtrPoint)->displayCoord();`. Just a guess.

Comment: It's not a "C++ convention".  It is rules of operator precedence in expressions and you assuming (incorrectly) that a pointer-to-a-pointer and a pointer-to-an-object are equivalent.  `*ptrPtrPoint->displayCoord()` is equivalent to `*(ptrPtrPoint->displayCoord())` and the expression `ptrPtrPoint->displayCoord()` is meaningless since `ptrPtrPoint` points at a pointer, not at a `Point`..  What you need is `(*ptrPtrPoint)->displayCoord()`.\

Comment: Just use `void runMainMenu(Point* &refPtrPoint) { refPtrPoint->displayCoord(); }` Then you don't have to worry about if `refPtrPoint` is null..

Comment: @Brandon "*Then you don't have to worry about if `refPtrPoint` is null*' - well, yes, you do. The reference itself can't be null, but the pointer it is referencing can still be null

Answer (score 6):

You have become a victim of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

First dereference to get a `Point*`, then use `->`

```
(*ptrPtrPoint)->displayCoord();
```

The compiler reads the original code as

```
*(ptrPtrPoint->displayCoord());
```

Comment: Bless you, my friend. Thank you.

Comment: @Will if this answered your question completely, consider [Accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to signal to others in the future that this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ***operator precedence***.

You need first to dereference the pointer to pointer and then call the function with the `->`. The right line of code is this:

```
(*ptrPtrPoint)->displayCoord();
```

pay attention to the operator precedence because in this case the compiler give you an error, but this isn't ever true. **Sometimes these errors can generate Undefined Behaviour or Unexepcted Behaviour.**